# How do I repair dhcp service after conficker infection on Windows 2003 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, dhcp, malware

How do I repair dhcp service after conficker infection on Windows 2003 Server?

If the server is restarted with DHCP then it keeps attempting to acquire a network address.  It seems to work fine if restarted with a static IP address however.

Comment: Just as a side comment: Why are you running your server with DHCP?  It seems bad form and you should be using a static IP address, at least I always do.

Comment: The server does not need a fixed IP address and so uses DHCP.

Answer (score 8):

Are you absolutely certain that you don't want to reinstall that machine? If it were a personal desktop, that would be one thing, but I'm not sure I'd trust a machine without a fresh install.

I may be paranoid here, though.

Comment: +1. When a machine has been infected, get any data off that you need and then re-install from scratch.

Comment: I personally would rebuild it.  Once it's been owned you are trusting various clean up tools that they really cleaned all of the cancer out.  You will sleep better after rebuilding it.

Comment: Good point but it would be nice to understand the problem as well :)

Comment: The problem is simple: malware. If you are the slightest bit unsure about whether or not your OS has been fully cleaned, err on the side of caution and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful:

[The DHCP service does not start when you start a Windows Server 2003-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927059)